# iOS - Image in Circle (UITableViewCell)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cornerradius

I have a static cell with UIImageView. I would like to have the image in a circle. I tried a lot of code...

Actually, I have :

```
        cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.height /2;
        cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3;
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultProfilePic.png"];
```

But it don't work... Only borderWidth work

What can I do ?

( I have Quartz framework)

Comment: The line you need is `cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Don't work...  Probably problem with my storyboard ?